# Google Analytics ecommerce tracking conversion inside iframe

Tags: php, iframe, google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking

I'm sort of new with tracking code and conversions so excuse my lack of knowledge in this matter...

I have a page (let's call it cart.php) with proper Google Analytics eCommerce tracking conversion snnipet and so far is working great and sending transactions data correctly (yay!).

Now I have page b (let's call it b.html) that does nothing but hold an iframe to cart.php, now I don't care for page b.html at all it doesn't even have tracking code. All I want to know is if by chance a user lands on page b.html which will be interacting with cart.php in an iframe, will google analytics and conversions be able to track the visits and transactions for cart.php only? Like I said I don't need to know if cart.php was visited and interacted directly or inside an iframe in page b.html just want to know if it was visited and a transaction was made regardless from where.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If all b.html does is hold the iframe for cart.php, and cart.php has the functioning tracking code, then yeah, it will work. I recommend testing though. So on page b.html, using a tool like Google Chrome Debugger or HTTPFox, and perform a transaction. You should see the request getting sent, and you should be able to see transaction appear in your transaction report in GA.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try doing that.